# How to apply a function to two elements of a list - Haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell

How can I apply a function to two elements of a list. For example:

Given the list `[red,star,blue,oval,orange,hexagon]` I want to apply the function to each pair `functionName(red,star)` `functionName(blue,oval)` `functionName(orange,hexagon)`

I'm guessing I would have to use recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes on way is to define a recursive function - what you need to think about (and what we don't know) is what should happen if the input list has uneven item-count?
And of course how do you want to collect the results of that function?

Assuming you just ignore the last singe element in an uneven list and that you want to collect the results into another list:

```hs
applyPairwise :: (a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
applyPairwise f (a1 : a2 : rest) = f a1 a2 : applyPairwise f rest
applyPairwise _ _ = []
```

Example:

```hs
> applyPairwise (+) [1..5]
[3,7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementing Carsten's answer, sometimes in functional programming (or programming in general) you might want to divide the tasks you want to do into several subtasks. So here are 2 tasks:

1. Pairing an element with its neighbour.
2. Applying a function to a list of pairs.

For the first task, we can simply define a function `pairing` that does the followings (and also assuming you want to ignore empty list or singleton list):

```hs
pairing :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
pairing []       = []
pairing [x]      = []
pairing (x:y:xs) = (x,y) : pairing xs
```

For example:

```
pairing [] == []
pairing [1] == []
pairing [1,2,3,4] == [(1,2),(3,4)]
pairing [1,2,3,4,5] == [(1,2),(3,4)]
```

Then for task 2, there is an operation in Haskell that applies a function to a list of elements called `map` (these functions that take a function as an argument are called higher-order functions):

For example:

```
f x = x^2

map f [0,1,2] == [0,1,4]
```

So we can now implement the function `applyPairwise` like this:

```
applyPairwise :: ((a,a) -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
applyPairwise f xs = map f (pairing xs)
```

Or even better using composition:

```hs
applyPairwise f = map f . pairing
```